# javascript and css3 website banners?

Tags: javascript, css, html

i would like to know if something like this:

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ProximityEffect/index2.html

would be able to be made into a website banner....?

let me re-phrase. I have ad space on website 200px x 600px. I normally give them animated gifs like cinemagraphs that i make in photoshop and everything needed is included once i upload my 200px x 600px .gif file. and before that .jpg or a .png....   I know it can be made into a banner but what I'm asking is how can i save that in a file that can be uploaded into my ad space.. obviously i would have no access to any css or html files of theirs... the goal of the project is to basically subdivide my space with other advertisers because well to be honest i just can't afford it.. so i would need each one of those boxes go to an external url... does this make any sense??

thanks for any direction you can give....

Comment: You're looking for the `<iframe>` tag.

Comment: and then i would host the files on my server????

Comment: Or some other server.

Comment: but correct me if i'm wrong, Wouldn't the webmaster of the site need to add my iframe to the site? actually i guess it would be the same work as adding a gif.... so great....looks like i can just do as you said...i was thinking i would have to embedd all this in a gif file...thanks and thanks for the fast response.....

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned an iframe would be your best bet.

I'm not sure if you're hosting the ad content or displaying the ads from your post, but either way a good option could be hosting the artwork on a shared CDN, which could make maintaining and editing the content much easier.

Obviously this depends on the nature of your artwork and relationship with your advertisers.